# When and how to use switchTo() method in webDriver (Selenium 2) to handle window/pop up

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble clicking or interacting with some page elements. They seem like normal DOM objects.  just buttons here is the code for one

```
<div style="clear: both; text-align: right">
 <img id="nextstep" class="nextbtn" height="21" alt="" src="/edit/images/author/next.png">
</div>
```

After clicking a button as "Upload file" another pop up window was opened. My task is to upload a file at pop up window and back to original window. I'll try to explain

I start a webDriver for

www.test.com   (<- made up name for example)

I login

click upload a file button

After this click our site redirects to www.foo.com instead of the above I am using the same driver created earlier and I try to interact with the buttons on the post upload page

button.click()

It never finds these buttons but they are there in firebug and appear normal.

Comment: As long as you are using the same window that webdriver opened you shouldn't need to switch. Can you post a snippet of the code that doesn't work?

Comment: I keep track of the list of windows (by handle String) and when i use switchTo() to get back to the original window I sometimes also use a JavaScript exectutor (in WebDriver) to get focus of the window and bring it up front (if switchTo fails to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to switch to the window again after the redirect.

Save you window handle:

```
String myWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

redirect to the page you want and then call switchTo using the window handle:

```
driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle );
```

Does your page contain any frames? It may also be possible that you are not in the correct frame after the redirect.

Comment: Would this work in the .Net version? I'm trying to get this to work in that but haven't found a good way to capture the title yet.  Maybe it's the fact that the new windows title is _blank...

Comment: @chaosr: your code is right. But I think it needs switching to defaultContent before myWindowHandle

Comment: @chaosr Can you please let me know how to open a link on another tab in same browser instead of opening a new window?